# Parse platform: can you disable requiring unique email for users?

Tags: xamarin.forms, parse-platform

Using the Parse database platform in Xamarin.Forms, even though .NET development on Parse seems to have gone extinct.

Still though, love that Parse!

Anyway it seems like Parse automatically rejects a new user sign-up if they have the same email as an existing account.

Is it possible to turn this off, so people can register multiple accounts with the same email address?

Comment: There is currently no way to disable. You'd need to store the email in another field in the case you want to allow duplicities.

Comment: I'll award you the answer if you want to post as an answerer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem , simply added a new field as customEmail and put email address there.

Comment: Can you accept my answer ? it would help me out a lot. Thanks